# Show external icons in my iOS app

Tags: ios, icons

Does iOS have a way of displaying icons belonging to other apps, eg.

1. App icons of Apple's built-in apps (eg. Apple's icon for the "Mail" app)
2. App icons of other apps (eg. the app icon for Google's "Hangouts" app)
3. Other icons in Apple's built-in apps (eg. Apple's icon for the "Print" action)

The purpose is to mimic "Send via Messages" in Safari, et. al. The alternative would be making copies of the icons and update them whenever they are updated by its creator (not fun).

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't use other app's icons to build a custom view, but you can use [UIActivityViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/index.html) that seems to be what you need.